# AWS Lambda and Numpy Libraries - Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy, aws-lambda

Trying to successfully run numpy on AWS Lambda.  The information I have read indicates that you need to use numpy libraries specifically compiled/compatible with AWS EC2.

Do do this I first followed the instruction to compile numpy on an ec2 instance, here:

[Installing numpy on Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732250/installing-numpy-on-amazon-ec2/25456990)

I then copied the newly built numpy into my Lambda application folder on my desktop, zipped up a Lambda deployment package containing the entire directory.

Upon running my Lambda function I still get this error:

**Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.**

Suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using moviepy, scipy and numpy in amazon lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749806/using-moviepy-scipy-and-numpy-in-amazon-lambda)

Answer (score 7):

Adding an answer for anyone who finds this old question.

Luckily, this problem has now been solved with Lambda Layer. AWS even [provides](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/) a NumPy and SciPy layer. You can attach it directly to your Lambda in the web console or use this ARN `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:668099181075:layer:AWSLambda-Python36-SciPy1x:2`

Comment: This worked for me! Just a quick note, it is only available with python 3.6 I believe. With my runtime of python 3.9 I wasn’t able to find it so I switched to 3.6 and was able to add it then

Answer (score 0):

**An easy way** to make your lambda function support the numpy library for python 3.7:

1. Go to your lambda function page
2. Find the Layers section at the bottom of the page.
3. Click on Add a layer.
4. Choose AWS layers as layer source.
5. Select AWSLambda-Python37-Scipy1x as AWS layers.
6. Select 37 for version.
7. And finally click on Add.

Now your lambda function is ready to support numpy.